# Google Ads API - How to get the access and referesh token using PHP

Tags: php, google-ads-api

I am following this package: https://github.com/googleads/google-ads-php. Here they said that I need to run this page:

https://github.com/googleads/google-ads-php/blob/main/examples/Authentication/GenerateUserCredentials.php

to terminal.

and I did it like:

```
php /locaation of the fie/GenerateUserCredentials.php
```

After that I can get a link which is something like that:

https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?response_type=code&access_type=offline&client_id=535777736006-d1rp8msevnls2pmihk7b8l23j3vra7duh.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fauth%2Fcallback&state=4e23ce963534701029c1a22d2de7848d034d8b0b0&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fadwords

(Above link is demo purpose)

So, When I click on this link I redirect to my google account and give access to them and after that I redirect back to this following URL:

http://localhost:3000/auth/callback?state=fddbaae6583b15aba552f682fe9f018233388533555f&code=4%2F0AfgeXvs4NV49mrqEBrl81ATRnXhqcu9x9ja8SAbaENSWhmNejGRGkZJE_AcD1aAFWdrlGg&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fadwords

Here you can see I have 2 params which is **state** and **code**.

**Now my question is how can I get the access token and refresh token using this URL?**

Answer (score 0):

> Here you can see I have 2 params which is **state** and **code**.

Now you can use them to get tokens.
Here is [an example](https://github.com/googleads/google-ads-php/blob/5a0b557eb3163800fb5d202b0f2cbfdd20bf5a2d/examples/Authentication/GenerateUserCredentials.php#L126-L140) from the google-ads-php source code (open the link for the full example/code):

```
// Exit if the state is invalid to prevent request forgery.
$state = $request->getQueryParams()['state'];
if (empty($state) || ($state !== $oauth2->getState())) {
    throw new UnexpectedValueException(
        "The state is empty or doesn't match expected one." . PHP_EOL
    );
};

// Set the authorization code and fetch refresh and access tokens.
$code = $request->getQueryParams()['code'];
$oauth2->setCode($code);
$authToken = $oauth2->fetchAuthToken();

$refreshToken = $authToken['refresh_token'];
print 'Your refresh token is: ' . $refreshToken . PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: Yes, I saw that page but where can I find the `$request` variable? can you send me the full php page?

Comment: `$request` variable is come from this line `function (ServerRequestInterface $request) use ($oauth2, &$authToken) {` so?

Comment: Because above page is not runing directory from the browser

Comment: `GenerateUserCredentials.php` is a full PHP page, they have everything there.

They're executing `GenerateUserCredentials::main();`, which uses `React\Http\HttpServer`, which provides them with the `$request` variable. 
They create a new HttpServer like this `$server = new HttpServer(...` and then call `$server->listen($socket);`. This `$server` takes care of the `$request` variable.

If you're using a regular web server (Apache or Nginx), you can use standard global PHP variables like `$_GET['code']` instead of `$request->getQueryParams()['code']`

Comment: If you're executing `GenerateUserCredentials.php` as it is, you should see tokens in your console (where you run `GenerateUserCredentials.php`). 

https://github.com/googleads/google-ads-php/blob/5a0b557eb3163800fb5d202b0f2cbfdd20bf5a2d/examples/Authentication/GenerateUserCredentials.php#L160-L165

Comment: No, I didn't see any tokens when I run that page on the console. I can see tts generate a URL only.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Could you please share what you can see in your browser (which redirects you to the final link with state and code parameters), and what you can see in the console where you run `GenerateUserCredentials.php`?

Comment: Well, I have managed my code. Thank You.